# "I don't believe anything that he says is true"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, any

> a. I do not believe that anything he says is true.

Isn't that sentence ambiguous?

First meaning: I believe that nothing he says is true.

Second meaning: I do not believe that just anything he says is true. Some are and some are not.

Comment: Third meaning:  I do not believe anything *that he says is true* -- but I just *might* believe it if he says something is *false*! :D

Comment: Many things in language are ambiguous. That's why they have to be put in context.

Answer (score 3):

In order to give the second meaning you would need to "everything" and not "anything".

In any context that I can think of, the first meaning is understood.  I don't find this sentence very ambiguous.

Comment: Or maybe to give the second meaning, you might say:  "I do not believe that *just* anything he says is true."  This sounds kind of stilted though, so your version with "everything" is a lot more natural